# Алгоритм определение угла поворота без условного перехода

Tags: алгоритм

Задача проста: имея два значения, задающих начальное `b` и конечное `e` угловое положение, выяснить минимальный угол поворота (т.е. не более 180 градусов) и его направление. Исходные углы заданы в градусах вещественной переменной. Диапазон `[0.0 ... 360.0)`.

Решение, в принципе, тоже простое:

1. Вычитаем из конца начало: `d = e - b;`
2. Если `abs(d) > 180`, то `r = d - sign(d) * 360`
3. Иначе `r = d`

`r` - искомый поворот, где знак задаёт направление: `+` - по часовой стрелке, `-` - против часовой.

Примеры:

- ```
  b = 350, e = 10  => r = +20
  ```
- ```
  b = 100, e = 0   => r = -100
  ```

Вопрос в следующем: можно ли избежать ветвления на шаге 2, а заодно обеспечить работоспособность алгоритма на любых значениях углов с учётом равенства `a = a + n * 360`, где `n` - любое целое число? Предположительно тригонометрические функции тут могут помочь.

Comment: Не понимаю почему `r` должен быть неотрицательным...

Comment: @MaxU он и не должен. Например `b = 10, e = 350` даст `r = -20`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну так поскольку ваше значение угла лежит в диапазоне от -360 до +360, то дробная часть от `(угол + 360.0)/360.0` умножить на 360... Можно прибавить 720 - чтоб уж наверняка :)

А, посмотрел внимательнее - вам нужно потом в (-180;+180) привести? Ну, добавьте

```
угол - floor(угол/180)*360
```

Ну, т.е. на С/С++

```
double f = e-b+360;
f -= floor(f/360)*360;
f -= floor(f/180)*360;
```

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: Откуда `-360...+360`? Итоговый угол должен быть не более `180` по модулю.

Comment: Так один от 0 до 360, второй там же. Результат - от 0 минус 360 до 360 минус 0?

Comment: Я так понимаю, `floor` вполне можно заменить на приведение к целому.

Comment: @alexolut Ну, в принципе да. Но зачем тогда `floor`? :) А, ну да, она при отрицательных работает не так...

Comment: не могли бы Вы добавить пояснения к каждому шагу и убрать неактуальную информацию?

Comment: @alexolut Простите, не очень уверен в том, что вы хотите. Не могли бы вы внести те исправления, которые считаете нужными? Был бы признателен.

Comment: Совсем забыл про это сообщение. Кстати, я так понимаю, что деление на 360 не нужно, как и добавление 360. Или я что-то упускаю?